# Define bounded type parameter in method type parameter list or in method argument

Tags: java, generics

what's the difference between the following two method definitions? Which one is preferred if they are the same?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
void sort1(List<T> list) {}

public static <T>
void sort2(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list) {}
```

And if the methods have more then one parameter that uses the type parameter, what's the difference then?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
void add1(List<T> list, T element) {}

public static <T>
void add2(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T element) {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not identical; for the type system, they are different. `sort1` accepts a `List` of a *type variable* and `sort2` accepts a `List` of a *wildcard*. Since you are doing a *sort* operation, that will modify the incoming parameter (the `List`); you might want to do this internally, for example:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort1(List<T> list) {
    list.set(0, list.get(0));
}

public static <T> void sort2(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list) {
    list.set(0, list.get(0)); // does not compile
}
```

only to find out that the second will not compile, because it uses a `wildcard` (there are ways to work-around this, though).

The same exact situation will arise in your second example, if you try to do:

```
public static <T> void add2(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T element) {
    list.add(element);
}
```

The general rule is that when you try to *modify*, you want to stick with type variables. If you can't do that, there are ways to work-around it, like `wildcard capture`, for example.

Comment: I understood that, but conveyed it wrongly in my answer.. my bad